# Guice creation errors: org.elasticsearch.Version

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm developing a simple java app in an eclipse IDE and with weblogic.
I'm using elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar and lucene-core-4.4.0.jar for it.

When I try to create a connection with elasticSearch I get an exception in this line:

**TransportClient tClient = new TransportClient(settings);**

And the trace I get is:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in org.elasticsearch.Version. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
at org.elasticsearch.Version.class(Unknown Source)
while locating org.elasticsearch.Version
for parameter 3 at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.(Unknown Source)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransportModule.configure(NettyTransportModule.java:39)

2) Could not find a suitable constructor in org.elasticsearch.Version. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
at org.elasticsearch.Version.class(Unknown Source)
while locating org.elasticsearch.Version
for parameter 4 at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.(Unknown Source)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.ClientTransportModule.configure(ClientTransportModule.java:39)

2 errors
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:344)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.initializeStatically(InjectorBuilder.java:151)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:102)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:93)
at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70)
```

I don´t know what is happening, as the class org.elasticsearch.Version is the one that comes in the elasticsearch-0.90.5.jar.

Any clue about it???

Thanks

Oscar

Comment: What is your settings?

Comment: Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", cluster).build();